# Are Stack Exchange websites built by multiple people?

Tags: support, questions

Is the Stack Exchange network built by one business, or it is a framework that can be downloaded and utilized by developers?

Comment: They are built by multiple people hired by one company. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange, Inc owns the Stack Exchange network and the software that runs the network.  They do not make it available for download, though [there are various open source clones available.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Comment: Are the clones legal?

Comment: @C15R You should ask a lawyer for your specific situation.  As far as I can tell, you are safe using a clone as long as 1) you don't copy the stack exchange visual design (ie, people can tell they aren't on a stack exchange network website when they visit your site because it doesn't look the same) and 2) if you use the data dumps from stack exchange, you properly attribute them with the appropriate links and visual/textual notices, etc.

Comment: I do not have a specific situation. I was just wondering is all.